# How to configure Application Insights sampling on Net Core HostBuilder?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm building .Net Core background service, using ApplicationInsights.WorkerService nuget package. The documentation regarding sampling configuration says to refer to this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#configure-sampling-settings

And it shows this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, TelemetryConfiguration configuration)
{
  var builder = configuration.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
  // For older versions of the Application Insights SDK, use the following line instead:
  // var builder = configuration.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;

  // Using adaptive sampling
  builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:5);

  // Alternately, the following configures adaptive sampling with 5 items per second, and also excludes DependencyTelemetry from being subject to sampling.
  // builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:5, excludedTypes: "Dependency");

  // If you have other telemetry processors:
  builder.Use((next) => new AnotherProcessor(next));

  builder.Build();

  // ...
}
```

Now on HostBuilder I don't see any extension methods that would give me the TelemetryConfiguration, source code of the nuget doesn't have it either:
https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/develop/NETCORE/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService/ApplicationInsightsExtensions.cs

So how do I get either TelemetryConfiguration or TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder on a HostBuilder? At the moment it looks like this:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use it as below:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

                    services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>((config)=>
                    {
                        var builder = config.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;

                        builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond: 5);
                        builder.Build();
                    }                    
                    );

                   // Your other code
                });
```

Comment: I wish there was a working sample available somewhere.  I am wasting so much time trying to get this to work with the idiosyncrasies of App Insights configuration :(

Comment: Getting exception : Application startup exception
System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration' for the parameter 'telemetryConfiguration' of method 'Configure' on type 'Omro.Sms.Infrastructure.MediasatAdapter.Api.Startup'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration' has been registered.

Comment: @AdrianNasui, could you please raise the issue in [application insights github](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues). I'm no longer working in the team, sorry for that.